# What is the opposite of Turbulent flow of water

Tags: vocabulary, adjectives, antonyms

Water that is not flowing could be described as 'calm' or 'still'.

How would you describe water that is flowing rapidly, but is not turbulent? (i.e. the flowing water is transparent, not white or distorted)

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=languidly+flowing&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clanguidly%20flowing%3B%2Cc0

Comment: I'm not sure that is what I meant, I particularly don't want to personify the water or it's flow. +1 for the relation to my user name though.

Comment: If you need a purely technical term, you might try looking up **[laminar flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laminar_flow)**.

Comment: @CopperKettle laminar flow is exactly what I was looking for, I'll accept the answer if you create one

Comment: Voila! But it's better always to clarify the intended context, this way you would get right answers faster! (0:

Comment: Don't discount TRomano's effort.  The definition [here](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/languid) suggests languid is suitable, and it's a word that is probably better known than 'laminar' to the average audience.

Comment: Languid also implies a slow pace, I am trying to describe water that flows rapidly. (Edited the question to reflect this.)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you need a purely technical term, you might try looking up **[laminar flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laminar_flow)**.

From Wikipedia:

> In fluid dynamics, **laminar flow** (or **streamline flow**) occurs when a fluid flows in parallel layers, with no disruption between the layers.

---

P.S. I've just recalled the word **unperturbed**. Checking for "unperturbed stream", "unperturbed flow" on Google brings up not that many results, but let it be here, just in case.

Answer (score 7):

I think "flowing" is actually the best word for your case. The word also means "with graceful movement", so that helps dispel any images of turbulent water.

*Streaming* or *running* also give the impression of water that's simply running, not rushing.

Comment: You can add adverbs for extra clarity, e.g. "Smoothly flowing".

Answer (score 3):

One word used as the opposite of turbulent, at least in reference to water, is ["placid."](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=placid&searchmode=none)

Comment: I was going to comment that placid usually refers to water that isn't flowing, but when I double checked my assumption I came across this: http://www.dnr.state.mn.us/watertrails/minnesotariver/index.html "It is a gentle, placid river".

Answer (score 2):

CopperKettle is correct that "laminar" flow is the technical term for the opposite of "turbulent" flow.

Laminar flow is often described as "smooth".  So, if you want a less technical answer, we could say the water is clear and **flowing smoothly**.

Answer (score -2):

I am surprised no-one has offered "quiet".

Comment: This is a legitimate option, of course, but you could improve this answer by providing sample usages of "quiet" in this context, or by finding a definition in the dictionary that matches (or both). Synonyms for _quiet_ include _tacit_ and _silent_, but neither of those would be a good word for describing water. If we assume some learners might have heard of "quiet libraries" but never "quiet water," we could make this answer a lot more helpful if it did more than suggest one word. Otherwise, this is more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: Sorry was using my mobile and still am. Example: they rowed across the quiet water of the lake. Implied: if they stopped rowing and listened they might hear the water lapping on the boat but if they were talking they would not have to raise their voices or listen any harder.

Comment: I don't think the phrase _quiet waters_ has much to do with the decibel level of the water. Compare and contrast Def 1 & 2 at [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/quiet). Normally, I would exhort you to **edit your answer** (as opposed to answering an appeal for more information in a comment), but we aim to avoid this kind of misinformation on the Stack Exchange, so, in this case, it's probably best to leave your assertion down here. As for being on your mobile, remember the [goal](http://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) of SE: to build a library of **detailed** answers.

Answer (score -4):

I think you could use the word, 'Trickle' in this case. Like, 'the water is flowing in a trickle,' as opposed to 'the water is gushing from the reservoir, which signifies turbulent flow.

Comment: Trickle vs gush is more about *volume* than smoothness; a trickle can often be quite turbulent on a small scale, while a gushing stream might be rather smooth.

Comment: @SoumyadeepKoley to echo Nathan, Think your turbulent water faucet vs the smooth surface of a wide, but powerful river.